# Page not found error for a single user

Tags: sharepoint-server

Is there any particular reason why only a single user gets Page not found error for a SharePoint site. He has Full control access and is able to access other SharePoint sites from PROD farm.

Comment: Have you checked server ULS logs?

Comment: Make sure that the page is published.